# How to change data folder in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

How to change data folder in sonarqube? 
I need to change the installation data folder to other location, is it possible?
Who is the responsible of write & change this folder? Is the wrapper?
I can change de location of h2 database but not the data folder location.
I use Sonarqube 5.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the software is a programming-related software, questions of the kind "can I change the installation directory" are general software questions and don't belong on StackOverflow. Also, you don't give *any* information on what you've tried, which platform you're on and which problems you encountered, so this question is unclear and too broad, too.

Comment: I´m using windows 32bits with a default installation of sonarqube 5.0. I need to change the data folder location because in "production mode" we can´t "touch" this folder (because we don´t have permissions on it) and sonarqube writes on it when the server start, and this is my problem basically

Comment: In my case:
We have installation on c:\Sonarqube and we have c:\Sonarqube\conf, c:\Sonarqube\data, etc... And I need to run c:\Sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-32\sonar.bat without change of c:\Sonarqube\data and their subfolders and archives. I´ve changed the location of h2 database changing sonar.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See in your `sonar.properties`:

```
# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp
```

You can uncomment the line `sonar.path.data` and set the value as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I did it for temp and logs but I don´t watch it for data folder, thanks a lot. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you'll have to follow the update instructions from sonarqube, as if you were to update sonarqueb to other folder/version, and remove the steps involved in the update.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

I would try this:

1. Stop the SonarQube server
2. Move the sonar old folder to your new folder, let's say 
   NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME.
3. Back up your database, just in case.
4. Start the web server inside your new_Sonarquebe_home

Comment: Thanks. I don´t want to change the database, I need to change the "data" folder location, and configure that location from one of the properties files but I can´t......