# How to set sonar.path.data to different drive

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to start SonarQube 7.5 and ([per the online documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/)) I tried to change the ElasticSearch storage path to a dedicated volume (Z:\data) by editing sonar.properties with the following lines:

```
# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
sonar.path.data=Z:\data
sonar.path.temp=Z:\temp
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to start.

```
PS C:\> &"C:\sonarqube-7.5\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat"
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\sonarqube-7.5\Z:data
jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\sonarqube-7.5\Z:data
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2491)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.createDirectory(AppFileSystem.java:80)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.reset(AppFileSystem.java:59)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:55)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:78)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What is the correct way to change the sonar.path.data (and sonar.path.temp) to a dedicated volume?

EDIT:
Thanks to [Simon Schrottner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3708208/simon-schrottner) I am now getting an entirely different error.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.io.IOException: 
Unable to create directory Z:\data
java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory Z:\data
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2491)
    at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.createDirectory(AppFileSystem.java:80)
    at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.reset(AppFileSystem.java:59)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:55)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

The rest, I think, is a permissions issue with Azure and beyond the scope of my original questions. Simon, if you'd post your suggestion as an Answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: What did you do to attempt changing the location? Did you do as this question says? [How to change data folder in sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116309/how-to-change-data-folder-in-sonarqube) Whatever you did, it's just appending `\Z:data` to the path which is invalid.

Comment: have you tried `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: @SimonSchrottner: You were correct. Sorry for the delay (RL got in my face, hard). If you want to submit your response as an answer you are, indeed correct.

Comment: @TomPadilla that is really nice of you thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong path delimiter.

As already mentioned in the comments - i highly suggest to use `/`(forward slash) instead of `\`(backward slash)

although windows is using normally a backward slash, this might not work with sonarqube. Java itself provides an own static field to determine/use the right separator [File.separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments, you should use a forward slash instead of back slash.

The value of your property should be:

`sonar.path.data=Z:/data`

Comment: Thank  you so much for reminding me of this. I tried the suggestion offered and it does work. I'd like to credit the original submitter, but I will +1 your answer. Thanks again.